# Get page dimensions using JavaScript in a Content Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to use a javascript method in a content page (Referencing  master page) to get the current screen dimensions, and write it to a label.

So far, I have had no luck. I tried doing it in both the master, and content page, but the method is simply not working.

Could someone please provide the solution for this?

MasterPage:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Lake, Smit People</title>
    <!--[if IE ]>  
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ProfileStypeSheetIE.css" />
    <![endif]-->  
    <!--[if !IE]>-->  
    <link href="ProfileStypeSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->  

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 { width: 378px; }
    </style>
</head>
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var height = screen.height;
    document.getElementById('<%= hiddenLabel.ClientID%>').value = height;

</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: how did you do it? I mean your code that is not working?

Comment: Please show your code, and tell us what web browser you're using.

Comment: @NewAmbition: Did you debug your javascript code? Are you getting screen height in the 'height' var?

Comment: I cant even do that. Either nothing is happening, or the actual javascript code is displaying on the top of my page.

Comment: @NewAmbition: Where have you used hiddenLabel? Please reproduce the problem and paste the complete code.

Comment: <%= hiddenLabel.ClientID%>. Try removing "=" and space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following?

```
<a href="javascript:alert
  ('Your resolution is ' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);">
     Click for your screen resolution </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try with theses lines, you specific case is the third (clientHeight  and clientWidth)

```
document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.scrollHeight // for the full size of the document
 
document.body.offsetWidth, document.body.offsetHeight //to the displayed size
 
document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight //customer for size displayed
```

Comment: Every attempt I make either displays the code as plain-text on the top of the page, or it doesn't show at all.

Comment: i'am sure that you have css problem (stylesheet) but not with this script

Comment: The only other script i have is the CCS script, which changes the style sheet based on the browser...