# How to get page dimensions in JavaScript or GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

In a web page I need to get the max x and y coordinates.

How this is achieved using JavaScript or with GWT specific code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is a bit unclear. You mean you want the page dimensions? Window dimensions?

Comment: @Jack I was looking for web page dimensions. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get page dimensions using JavaScript in a Content Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828553/get-page-dimensions-using-javascript-in-a-content-page)

Comment: @Jack there are GWT specific methods for this, so it is not a duplicate of a JavaScript question.

Comment: @ColinE Well, that's why it says "possible" duplicate, but thanks for mentioning that there's a GWT answer for it.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the `Window` class, it has methods for getting the client height /width:

- [getClientHeight](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#getClientHeight%28%29)
- [getClientWidth](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#getClientWidth%28%29)

Comment: same as for @ATTA, "On Windows Phone 10 these heights do not take in account the clock line above page and calculations of places on screen fail compared to other platforms and phone versions. How to battle against that mismatch?"

Answer (score 3):

**GWT :**

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;

int height =Window.getClientHeight();
int width =Window.getClientWidth();
```

Comment: On Windows Phone 10 these heights do not take in account the clock line above page and calculations of places on screen fail compared to other platforms and phone versions. How to battle against that mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `scrollHeight` and `scrollWidth` for getting whole page dimension.

```
var pageheight=document.body.scrollHeight ;
var pageweight=document.body.scrollWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the browser window, use:

```
Window.getClientHeight()
Window.getClientWidth()
```

To get the size of the html page, use:

```
Document.get().getScrollHeight()
Document.get().getScrollWidth()
```